# how to query pricing from AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, boto, aws-sdk

I found that AWS provide these links for query pricing of AWS services,
i found these links and i want to query on OnDemand linux cost for ec2.
But i don't know which one of these is used for which purpose.

first->
http://aws-assets-pricing-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/pricing/ec2/linux-od.js

second->
[a0.awsstatic.com/pricing/1/ec2/linux-od.min.js](http://a0.awsstatic.com/pricing/1/ec2/linux-od.min.js)

third->
https://a0.awsstatic.com/pricing/1/deprecated/ec2/pricing-on-demand-instances.json

Please tell me which link show which cost.

I found these links here,

[github.com/erans/ec2instancespricing/commit/901d746da8fe40241261ff1a461596151611621b](http://github.com/erans/ec2instancespricing/commit/901d746da8fe40241261ff1a461596151611621b)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want current pricing for EC2 (or any other AWS service), you should use the new [AWS Price List API](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-price-list-api/).

- EC2 JSON (39.9MB): https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/index.json
- EC2 CSV (26.8MB): https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/index.csv

Once you've downloaded one or both files, it'll be up to you to scan, search, or parse through it either manually or programmatically. This is more work than just grabbing a much smaller third-party JSON file, but this Price List API is guaranteed by Amazon to be up-to-date.

I'm expecting others to create tools that parse these files and retrieve specific data, but I haven't found any yet.

Comment: which price this link contain ?
 https://a0.awsstatic.com/pricing/1/deprecated/ec2/pricing-on-demand-instances.json

Comment: Deprecated in this case means "not current" and I just confirmed that. In that JSON file, the on-demand price of an m1.small is listed at $0.06. The actual current price is $0.044. ( ref: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/previous-generation/ )

Comment: yes,that's why i confused.
Is any significant of this price ?

Comment: Understandable. No significance of the pricing in that JSON file other than a snapshot of what the prices were before recent price cuts. A reliable programmatic source of current pricing data is something that folks have wanted for a long time, so it's great that Amazon is providing it now. If you don't have any other follow-up questions and you're satisfied with my answer, feel free to accept it. Thanks!

Comment: one last thing that i want to ask that is it possible that there is an instance type whose price is in this file and not in latest list ?

Comment: As far as I know, Amazon deprecates instance types in favor of new ones, but doesn't actually remove them. The pricing does skew in favor of the new types, though. Better specs for a lower price in most cases.

Comment: prices of some previous generation instances Eg. m1.xlarge are not available on second link,so we have to use third link for find prices of some previous generation instances.

Comment: The accuracy of those three files in your question is not guaranteed. The AWS Price List API is less convenient given the size of the responses, but Amazon guarantees the accuracy of the data. I expanded my answer with links to the JSON and CSV files for EC2.